# Logic formal proofs find the derived statements

Tags: logic

1.(K•L)>M
2. K>L
Therefore K>[(K•L)•M]
3. K>(K•L) 2,Abs.
4.
5. K>[(K•L)•M]
 This is what I have so far but I don’t know if I started Off right can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a conditional proof this is quite easy. Just asume $K$ and then you can derive $L$ from $2$. Then you would have $K \wedge L$ to derive $M$ from $1$. From there you can get $(K \wedge L) \wedge M$ and discharge with  $K \rightarrow ((K \wedge L) \wedge M).$ However a direct proof is by no means obvious. Here is a direct proof:

$1. (K \wedge L) \rightarrow M \\
2. K \rightarrow L  \vdash  K \rightarrow ((K \wedge L) \wedge M)) \\
3. K \rightarrow (K \wedge L) \quad (2 \, Absorption) \\
4. K \rightarrow M \quad (1,3 \, Hypothetical \, Syllogism) \\
5. \neg K \vee  (K \wedge L) \quad (3 \, Material \, Implication) \\
6. \neg K \vee M \quad (4 \, Material \, Implication) \\
7. (\neg K \vee (K \wedge L)) \wedge (\neg K \vee M) (5,6 \, Conjunction ) \\
8. \neg K \vee ((K \wedge L) \wedge M) \quad (7 \, Distribution) \\
9. K \rightarrow ((K \wedge L) \wedge M) \quad (8 \, Material Implication)$